Customize sources of word suggestions?
I just discovered the webversion of vscode and it seems amazing for big chunk of work I have to do regular. In particular, the IntelliSense is unexpectedly awesome because it automatically populated itself with all the data from my git and that already saves me a ton of time.
That said, part of my repo is a list of misspelled words and the correction, so these factor in the recommendations as well. I can create a clean list, but I'd like to keep VSCode from suggesting content from of my text correction list. I strongly suspect this shouldn't be too hard, but I'm not quite sure how.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? It'd be greatly appreciated!
Looked through the IntelliSense documentation and did a brief google search, but didn't really find the correct way to solve it.
